# 'mono --trace myapp'?

Tags: debugging, mono, ubuntu-12.04

Ubuntu 12.04, Mono 2.10.8.1-5

I have built the "hello world" console app that MonoDevelop creates as a default. It runs as expected. When I add the trace option (directed into a file, or not), I get stuff like this:

```
[0x7f24da6eb740: 0.00000 0] ENTER: (wrapper runtime-invoke) <Module>:runtime_invoke_void__this___object (object,intptr,intptr,intptr)([System.OutOfMemoryException:0x7f24da52af60], 0x7fff953e6510, (nil), 0x40e79a70, )
[0x7f24da6eb740: 0.00012 1] ENTER: System.OutOfMemoryException:.ctor (string)(this:0x7f24da52af60[System.OutOfMemoryException monotracetest.exe], [STRING:0x7f24da551e70:Out of memory], )
[0x7f24da6eb740: 0.00021 2] ENTER: System.SystemException:.ctor (string)(this:0x7f24da52af60[System.OutOfMemoryException monotracetest.exe], [STRING:0x7f24da551e70:Out of memory], )
[0x7f24da6eb740: 0.00030 3] ENTER: System.Exception:.ctor (string)(this:0x7f24da52af60[System.OutOfMemoryException monotracetest.exe], [STRING:0x7f24da551e70:Out of memory], )
[0x7f24da6eb740: 0.00031 3] LEAVE: System.Exception:.ctor (string)
```

..going on for nearly 900 lines about stack overflows, out of memory, and more innocent looking things.

I've not found any documentation on the trace option beyond '--help-trace'. What should I be expecting? Is this actually reporting problems? When I wrap the 'console.writeline("hello world")' in a try catch block, no exception is thrown. (Of course, presumably an unhandled exception would have crashed the program.)

My original program was to test calling a library of native code, and I reduced it to this to see where it failed.

How do I separate the wheat from the chaff?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is the expected output: there is no exception thrown, but the runtime needs to build some objects at startup (for example the OutOfMemory exception object: when the condition happens there may be no memory anymore to allocate it!).

As for reducing the output, what is not clear in --help-trace?
For example, if you want to get traces only of classes and methods in the System.IO namespace, you will issue:

> mono --trace=N:System.IO program.exe

Comment: So it's building the exception objects ahead of time so that they'll be available if needed. Reasonable enough. However, since it needs to do this, I'd think there would be a simple flag to turn all that off, or even that it would be off by default. I suppose --trace=N:mynamespace is the way to go.  Thanks!